# How can i get my ul element bullet point start from left corner

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin, padding

I would like my bullet point start from left corner. Below image shows my bullet point adding some padding or margin on the left corner.

[image]

CSS

```
.midContent {  
overflow:hidden;
}
 .midContent div {
min-height: 200px;
padding: 10px;
}
#leftDiv { 
float:left;  
width:49%; 
}
#rightDiv { 

 }
.midContent ul{
margin:0;
padding-left: 1em;
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="midContent">
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <ul>
            <li> Manufacturing;</li>
            <li>Professional services;</li>
          </ul>
    </div>

<div id=“rightDiv">
        <ul>
            <li> Manufacturing;</li>
            <li>Professional services;</li>
          </ul>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `.midContent ul{
 margin:0;
 padding-left: .5em;
 list-style-type:disc;
}`

Comment: The above code worked well to me. Thanks @anshual gera

Answer (score 0):

Add style `padding-left: 1em;` to your `ul`